# Why does CNN start at 99.8% Accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, classification

This is very strange: my CNN has a high training and validation accuracy from the very first epoch. Is it even learning? Or is it memorizing?

Take a look at the Train/Val. Accuracy:
[image]

The y-axis is accuracy and x-axis is # Epochs. The CNN has Dropout to reduce overfitting, which is why I'm confused -- is it memorizing the training data? If that was the case, the confusion matrix would be all over the place, but the CNN correctly classifies 998/1000 images. Why is this happening?

Below is the MWE and the full code is [**here**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qSM91iQ-jElizS6_7COY7OWgQGEQPGRT?usp=sharing):

```
"""# Import Libraries"""

# Import Libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

"""# Load Dataset"""

import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://barisciencelab.tech/TrainingSet.tar.gz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin = dataset_url,
                                   fname = "TrainingSet",
                                   untar = True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

"""# Display # Images to check"""

print(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png')))
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png')))
print(image_count)

"""# Display sample image"""

pip install sklearn

import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

graphs = list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png'))
PIL.Image.open(str(graphs[6]))

"""# Define Image Dimensions & Batch Size"""

batch_size = 32
img_height = 36
img_width = 36

"""# Create Training & Validation Sets (80%, 20%)"""

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

"""# Define 3 Classes"""

class_names = ['Cubic Sinusoidal', 'Linear Sinusoidal', 'Quadratic Sinusoidal']
print(class_names)

"""# Supervised Learning (9 Samples from the Training Set)"""

!pip install skimage

from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subGraphs = []
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'white'
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    subGraphs.append(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

"""# Normalize Inputs (/255px)"""

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixels values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

"""# Architechture of CNN (3 Conv2Ds, 3 MaxPool2Ds, 2 Dense and Flatten)"""

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# Load the TensorBoard notebook extension
# %load_ext tensorboard

import tensorflow as tf
import datetime

# Clear any logs from previous runs
!rm -rf ./logs/

num_classes = 3

# IDENTIFY PARAMETERS FOR Conv2D(A,B, )
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'), #32 FILTERS and square stride of size 3
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(
  optimizer='adam', 
  loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

epochs = 3

initial_learning_rate = 0.01
decay = initial_learning_rate / epochs

def lr_time_based_decay(epoch, lr):
    return lr * 1 / (1 + decay * epoch)

history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs= epochs,
  callbacks= [tensorboard_callback, tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_time_based_decay, verbose=1)]
)

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# %tensorboard --logdir logs/fit

model.summary()

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Train & Val. Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Train & Val. Loss')
plt.show()

"""# Image Input Array"""

pip install glob2

preds = []

for i in range(0,999):

  lin_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Refath/SinusoidalAnalyzer/main/Validation/Graph_"+str(i)+".png"
  lin_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Graph_'+str(i)+'.png', origin=lin_url)

  img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
      lin_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
  )

  img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
  img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

  predictions = model.predict(img_array)
  score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

  print(
      "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
      .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
  )
  preds.append(np.argmax(score))

print(preds)
results = []

for i in range(0,len(preds)):
  results.append(0)

for i in range(0, len(preds)):
  if preds[i] == 0:
    results[i] = "Cubic"
  elif preds[i] == 1:
    results[i] = "Linear"
  else: 
    results[i] = "Quadratic"

print(results)

len(preds)

"""# Confusion Matrix"""

actual = [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1]
tf.math.confusion_matrix(preds, actual)

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline
import numpy as np

y_true = actual
y_pred = preds
data = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Cubic','Linear','Quadratic'], index = ['Cubic','Linear','Quadratic'])
df_cm.index.name = 'Actual'
df_cm.columns.name = 'Predicted'
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
sn.set(font_scale=1.4)
sn.heatmap(df_cm, cmap="Blues", annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 16}, fmt='g')
```

Comment: What about testing? Have you done it? If it performs so well in testing, so it's nothing wrong with the model/program.

Comment: I've tried adding a Testing Set, but for some reason it seems to be especially difficult to implement in TensorFlow, which supports only Training and Validation Sets by default. However, I've tested the network in other ways, such as by mislabeling the validation set, handicapping it (i.e., removing one class from training and giving it as a new instance), feeding random images, etc. They all work as expected. I'm just confused as to *why* the network is starting from such a high accuracy from the very first epoch. That just doesn't make sense. Or is it not something to worry about?

Comment: What are the statistics of the data to be learned?  How many items in each category?  Are there obvious simple and consistent differences between items in different categories (light vs dark, for example)?

Comment: @rb3652 You can do `model.predict()` on the test set and evaluate it with sklearn's `classification_report`

Comment: If the dataset is simple to classify like MNIST dataset, then it's fine to get the high accuracy at the start. If you want to test your model then try augmenting with random horizontal/vertical flip and rotation etc and check.